# How can I print a byte along with a string?

Tags: java, byte, printf, output, system.out

I have a byte:

```
byte STX = 0x02;
```

Printing it as it is with `printf` returns `0x02` which is what I want:

```
System.out.printf("0x%02X", STX);
```

However, I want to concatenate it with strings like below or similar:

```
System.out.println("Found " +  STX + " at " + i);
```

But it returns the integer value. How can I therefore print a byte and concatenate it with a string?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `printf` all the way? I find it clearer to stick to one formatting style for a whole string - either concatenation all the way, or `printf`-formatting all the way.

Comment: The reason is because I don't know how to! If there's a way to System.out.printf all the way do tell!

Comment: Do you need the padding of the leading zero? The byte value of STX is "0x2". You can clean up the formatting a little more by using `%#2x` in the format string which will give an output value of `0x2`

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

`System.out.println("Found " +  String.format("0x%02X", STX) + " at " + i);`

or even better:

`System.out.println(String.format("Found 0x%02X at %d", STX, i));`

or even better:

`System.out.printf("Found 0x%02X at %d%n", STX, i);`

Comment: Why use String.format within System.out.println, when `System.out.printf` can do both in one call?

Comment: Because someone working on the codebase at some point in time will forget to add the "%n" and will mess up any printed output

Comment: Like me above. Adding the %n now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.println("Found " +  String.format("0x%02X", STX) + " at " + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is effectively a copy of an existing answer, which was downvoted... but as your comment now indicates that you'd welcome such an option...

You can use `printf` to format your *whole* string:

```
System.out.printf("Found 0x%02X at %d%n", STX, i);
```

Here the `0x%02X` is the part you already know; the `%d` is the format specifier for `i`; the `%n` is the platform-specific newline.

I find it clearer to use *one* style of formatting throughout a statement: either `printf`/`String.format` formatting *or* string concatenation, rather than a mixture of the two.

If you find yourself wanting the formatting without printing to the console, just use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead:

```
String text = String.format("Found 0x%02X at %d", STX, i);
```

(That's assuming you don't want the line separator in that case.)

See the [`Formatter` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for all the options in format strings.